# Comparing strings inside of two objects

Tags: object, equals

I've been trying to compare the string inside of the `Card()` `object` with the other `Card()` objects to check for duplicates when the playing cards are dealt.

Except when printing out the compare statement i'm getting something like `Card@97sd829`. I made my own `Equals()` `method` for comparison of the `object` `Card()` inside of the `Class` but still to no avail.

I've tried using the override of the `equals()` `object` but I'm getting an `error` saying it needs to be inside of a superclass?

```
public static boolean Equals(Card a, Card b) {
    String str1 = a.toString();
    String str2 = b.toString();
    if (str1.equals(str2))
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}
public static boolean checkDuplicate (Card a, Card b, Card c, Card d, Card e){
    int num = 5;
    boolean bool = true;
    if (Card.Equals(a, b)||Card.Equals(a, c)||Card.Equals(a, d)||Card.Equals(a, e)||
    Card.Equals(b, c)||Card.Equals(b, d)||Card.Equals(b, e)||Card.Equals(c, d)||
    Card.Equals(c, e)||Card.Equals(d, e)); num--;
    if (num == 5)
        bool = false;
    else
        bool = true;
    return bool;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the toString() method of the Object.class to get a String representation of your cards.

The default implementation of toString() contains the hash of the object. Since you have two different Card-objects the toString() method of these objects produces different output.

A better way would be to implement equals() in the Card class. Then you could check for equality with a.equals(b).

If you want advice how to implement Card.equals() you should post the source code of the Card class.